# Are password managers like 1Password trustworthy?

Tags: security, passwords

I like the idea of using a password manager to help me maintain separate, random passwords for each site I visit.

I *don't* like the idea of typing all my logins into a single piece of software.  How do I know that it won't immediately transmit them to its mothership?

What evidence is there for the trustworthiness (or not) of these programs?  (Especially 1Password.)

Comment: If I may suggest: use keepass + dropbox instead.

Comment: How do you know we won't lie to you making you choose an unsafe alternative?

Comment: Strongly dissent from the claim that this question is "not constructive". It's a question any piotential user of password managers is likely to ask, and it has some straightforward answers.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a password by hand, your browser knows what you entered. How do you know the browser isn't transmitting to the mothership? Because you trust the company that supplied it.

You can't function offline with a 100% guarantee of security and privacy. The best you can do is to only allow openings to people you trust. Naturally, you should extend your trust with care, but if a company is doing business with a lot of people like you, it's in their interests not to abuse your trust — particularly when their whole business model depends on it.

Rather than worrying about conspiracies to steal your passwords, you should worry about *unintended* releases of your information. Do they have competent security people? Are the stored passwords encrypted in a way that allows unauthorized access?

Comment: I like your argument from self interest better than @moab's argument from authority.  But I still wonder if there is any kind of certification or review, which is related to your questions about competence.

Comment: @Eric The certification approach is actually the basis of Moab's claim that Open Source is better. There's just no way to audit a closed-source code base for back doors. But when you have a lot of people looking at your code in a public repository, they're going to spot security holes, deliberate or accidental. Of course, you still have to extend some trust to whoever *built* the application, unless you built it yourself -- something some tinfoil hat types insist on doing.

Answer (score 0):

Open source and designed by Bruce Schneier, trustworthy as it gets

http://www.schneier.com/passsafe.html

Comment: Argument from authority?  I suppose if there's also an active open source community reviewing the code, that constitutes evidence, but how to judge what kind of review it's really getting?

Comment: Trustworthy perhaps, but too limited for most users. No syncing, no support for any platform other than Windows, no ability to fill in or memorize forms....

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch OP never asked about anything other than trustyworthyness

Comment: @PleaseDelete Your argument applies to all software, trustworthy based on who designed it.

Comment: downvote because the answer is incorrect, or does not answer the OP question, not because you don't like it.

Comment: @Moab True, the question was "what's the evidence of trustworthiness?" so my critique of the software was indeed offtopic.  But you didn't answer the question. You just threw out the name of software you considered trustworthy without adequate explanation. *I* had to explain OS trustworthiness for you. And no, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: "Bruce Schneier" is trustworthy, research it yourself.

Comment: I didn't say he wasn't. But you didn't explain that.